# Emacs inferior-lisp get result of evaluation

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am sending regions from my current buffer to inferior-lisp buffer using,

```
(lisp-eval-string sexpr-str)
```

What I would like to do is get the result back. I have tried saving point before and after eval call and build a string from that but I need to add a delay between point calls to wait for eval to run which does not work if the delay is shorter then what it takes to eval the string.

Comment: Have you looked at the [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/)  Lisp interaction mode? I haven't used it extensively, but it seems like it might have what you need built in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending your string to the inferior lisp process, you want to convert it and eval it directly.  I think this would be:

```
(eval (read-from-string mystring))
```

Alternatively, if you want to run an external process but don't want to have output go into a buffer, then don't start an asynchronous process.  Use the the **accept-process-output** call to get the output.

Comment: a) Then why is your post tagged elisp? and b) it works in common lisp, also.